# O comando pip3 foi "estragado", o que devo fazer?

Tags: linux

tudo bem?
Eu havia feito alguns testes para instalar uma biblioteca no python e infelizmente acabei "estragando" o comando. O fato é o sistema não o reconhece como instalado, mas quando utilizo o comando

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Ele não o instala, segue a mensagem que aparece:

```
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
python3-pip is already the newest version (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.1).
0 pacotes atualizados, 0 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 23 não atualizados.
```

A mensagem me leva a crer que a instalação já foi feita, porém se utilizarmos o comando

```
whereis pip3
```

ou

```
whereis pip2
```

ou

```
whereis pip
```

Sempre retorna a mesma resposta:

```
pip3:
```

ou

```
pip2:
```

ou

```
pip:
```

Agora podemos notar que apesar de não existir nenhuma versão do pip no meu sistema, ele não pode ser instalado. O fato foi causado por um erro meu, devo confessar(utilizei o "dpkg" para desinstalar tentar reinstalar novamente depois), mas será que não existe reparação?

Agradeço desde já,
Bartolomeu.

Comment: Olá, essa pergunta seria melhor aproveitada se fosse postada no [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) ou no [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), ambos pertencentes à Stack Exchange. As perguntas lá tem como contribuidores usuários de sistemas Linux no dia a dia, e podem dar respostas mais completas e embasadas, enquanto o Stack Overflow (tanto o [original](https://stackoverflow.com/) quanto o [brasileiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) ) são focados em problemas com programação, e temo que você não conseguirá a resposta desejada pelo simples fato de ...

Comment: ... de as pessoas não esperarem essa pergunta. Temos diversos exemplos de perguntas pertencentes à outros sites da rede exchange que receberam ótimos votos e respostas incríveis quando postados em seus respectivos sites, mas, quando postadas aqui, não foram tão bem recebidas.

Comment: Espero ter ajudado. Por favor, acesse nosso [guia de sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas?cb=1), e seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo cometário, não tinha conhecimento desses sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

decidi reinstalar o Python(no caso utilizo Python3), para isso utilizei o seguinte comando:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3
```

Assim o Python foi reinstalado e para garantir que estava tudo bem, decidi reinstalar também o pip(no caso o pip3).

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-pip
```

Assim consegui fazer o pip funcionar,

agradeço a atenção e espero que tenha ajudado alguém.